# How to not add a string to a text area if it contains something - Java

Tags: java, string, textarea, inputstream

I have the following:

```
InputStream inputFromServer
TextArea t
String display
String validation
```

String display holds the data from the inputstream, it then adds it to the text area. I want to check that if display contains validation then dont write it to the text area. Here is the code I currently have:

```
while ((inputFromServer.read())!=-1)
{
    display = display + ((char)inputFromServer.read());
    t.setText(s);
}
```

I want something like:

```
while ((inputFromServer.read())!=-1)
{
    display = display + ((char)inputFromServer.read());
    if display contains validation {
        THEN DONT WRITE IT TO THE TEXT AREA
    } 
    else{
        t.setText(s);
    }
}
```

If the method is completely wrong then can someone guide me in the right direction please? Thanks

Comment: what's sort of validation? if a current string is in it?

Comment: The string variable gets initialized in another method when the user types something into a textField. What they type in becomes the string inside the validation variable. The code I have given always reads from server and adds to textarea. I dont want it to add any message that contains the validation string. All other messages should add to the textarea

Comment: if the textarea contains the validation variable, should it the t.setText add nothing, or only the sting but without the validation string? and is the validations strings are known in advanced?

Comment: add nothing - It either adds the whole message or skips that message if it contains the validation string

Comment: If you are only looking to see if the string contains a certain substring you can do `display.contains("hello");` or `display.toLowerCase().contains("hello");` if you don't care about case.

Comment: When the program first runs, the validation variable is empty...it only gets initialized when the user types something into a textfield (this is in another method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
while ((inputFromServer.read())!=-1)
{
    display = display + ((char)inputFromServer.read());
    if (!display.contains(VALIDATION_STRING) {
        t.setText(s);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your recent comment made it unclear. can u give us more info regarding the VALIDATION variable? how is it initalized? when? are those fixed String s?

Comment: I tried that - it works but when the display string contains the validation string, then onwards no other message gets added to the textarea, even it it doesnt contain it.

Comment: The validation variable is declared as String validation; - in a textfields actionlistener, it takes the users input and makes it the validation variabe = validation = inputfromUser.getText();

Comment: why would it? look at the display = .... line. once it contains the validation string, you only add to it. it would always contain it unless ur clear it from the display.

Answer (score 0):

Ok since the validation `String` is possibly uninitialized you can check against that

```
display += ((char)inputFroMServer.read());
if(validationString.equals("") || !display.contains(validationString)) {
      t.setText(display);
}
```

Or like I said in my comment you can do:

```
!display.toLowerCase().contains(validationString.toLowerCase())
```

if you don't care about case

Also if you are going to editing the display string a bunch of times you should consider using a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/)